# How to only run Google App Engine cronjobs in Django if the caller is the Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, deployment

I have been deployed my Django project to the Google App Engine. I wanna add cronjobs to my Django project and there is a cool feature for it in Google App Engine.

If I understand it well, I must create GET functions for my cronjobs in my views.py. But how do I make them callable only by the App Engine and no one else? *Or, maybe there is a better solution for cronjobs in Django?*

Comment: It really depends on your needs - you should provide more information about your application to give a better context. AWS gives a free tier, that would be good for a simple, "4 fun" application and to learn something for free. If you want to deploy something that will require a better performance (because of a bigger traffic or due to complexity of calculations in your app), you should consider something else - but it depends on your needs.

Comment: @rafaljusiak I still developing the application, it's not for fun, and I don't know yet how big traffic I can except.

Comment: If you don't know how big will be your traffic you shouldn't worry about it at the early stage. I think that you can try with AWS free tier in this case (EC2 + RDS and S3 if needed) - just because it is free. If your site will be too slow for users because of the server limitations, then you can always switch to some paid plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate your request by checking header `X-Appengine-Cron` at your endpoint.  This header is only supplied when your endpoint is triggered by GAE cron jobs.

Reference link:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests